# Syntax error near unexpected token newline message after executing a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, github, download

I use shell in PUTTY to execute a remote script from Git:

```
curl -s https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh >dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh
./dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh
```

But suddenly received a syntax error:

> Syntax error near unexpected token newline
>
> <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Are you running it with the default `sh` shell or with `bash`, can you try `bash dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix URL in your curl command:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh
```